# Need a customized program that can be used to track multiple workers signing up for work in an organized fashion

Tags: scheduled-tasks, workflow

I manage a group of virtual providers that need to sign up for tasks in a fixed order.  The task is displayed in order of need and the workers communicate in a MS Teams chat.  Currently, an order of workers is declared in the chat but then the workers need to remember or refer to the order to keep track of where they are in the order.  The order also changes during the day as worker shifts change.  Ideally, I am looking for a way to display the order of workers selected, display where the workers are in the order, and have some way to display who is next up to select a task.  It would be best to display within MS Teams but could be a separate website.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts or help

I have very basic Excel skills and was able to create a worker order but it wasn't dynamic enough to be useful